# Is there a consolidated or partial list noting the use of quasiquotation with provers?

Tags: implementation, quasiquotation, provers

In checking to see if any provers (proof assistants, theorem provers, interactive theorem prover) make use of quasiquotation I was quickly surprised at what started showing up with a Google search.

- Type-Directed Elaboration of Quasiquotations ([pdf](https://www.davidchristiansen.dk/pubs/type-directed-elaboration-of-quasiquotations.pdf))
- Growing a Proof Assistant ([pdf](https://www.williamjbowman.com/resources/cur.pdf))
- HOL Light QE* ([pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.00405.pdf))
- A quasi-quoting library for Agda, supporting automatic de Bruijn management. ([GitHub](https://github.com/UlfNorell/quasi-quote))

However I did not find a consolidated or partial list. I was even hoping for an [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage) entry but sadly there was none.

Is there a consolidated or partial list noting the use of quasiquotation with provers?

---

Partial list of programming languages using Quasiquotation or similar to better understand what it brings to the table.

- Clojure [Quote](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote)
- F# [Code Quotations](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualfsharpdocs/blob/main/docs/conceptual/code-quotations-%5Bfsharp%5D.md)
- Haskell [Quasiquotation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Quasiquotation)
- Janet - Noted in [Special Forms](https://janet-lang.org/docs/specials.html)
- Julia [Quote Expressions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/ast/#Quote-expressions)
- Lisp [Quote](https://jtra.cz/stuff/lisp/sclr/quote.html)
- OCaml Camlp5 [Quotations](https://camlp5.github.io/doc/html/quot.html)
- Racket [Quasiquoting](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html)
- Rust [Quote](https://docs.rs/quote/latest/quote/)
- Scala [Quasiquotes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html)
- Scheme [Quasiquote](https://icem.folkwang-uni.de/%7Efinnendahl/cm_kurse/doc/schintro/schintro_129.html)
- SWI-Prolog [quasi_quotations](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=quasiquotations)

---

**EDIT**

In learning more about an answer for this am finding that LISP Quote, OCaml Camlp5 quotations and Quasiquotations have some heredity.

Here are some papers and pages to better understand all this heredity.

- "The Roots of Lisp" ([pdf](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/llog/jmc.pdf)) by Paul Graham
- "Quasiquotation in Lisp" ([pdf](https://3e8.org/pub/scheme/doc/Quasiquotation%20in%20Lisp%20(Bawden).pdf)) by Alan Bawden
- "The Roots of Quotation" (with relation to R) ([HTML](https://www.milesmcbain.com/posts/the-roots-of-quotation/)) by Miles McBain
- "Why It's Nice to be Quoted: Quasiquoting for Haskell" ([pdf](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150FP/archive/geoff-mainland/quasiquoting.pdf)) by Geoffrey B. Mainland

Comment: [This comment by Mike Shulman on one of my questions](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/list-of-general-purpose-coq-sublanguages-for-defining-custom-tactics?noredirect=1#comment2246_1035) mentions a Coq extension [coq-elpi](https://github.com/LPCIC/coq-elpi) that appears to include quasiquotation at a syntactic level. `lp:{{ }}` and `{{ }}` seem to be a pair of quotes and anti-quotes. Also, would something like `` ` `` and `,` in Common Lisp count as quasiquotation?

Comment: I have another question about this question. Are you looking for a list of provers supporting quasiquotation (or another similar form of extensible syntax) maintained elsewhere or are you looking to make this question and its answers into such a list?

Comment: Never mind. You actually answered my question above in an earlier comment. Whoops.

Comment: "Is there a consolidated or partial list noting the use of X with provers?"  I would say probably not for most X.  I have trouble even finding even a good list of what provers are out there much less their specific features.

Comment: However, I think Lean has quasiquotes.  (I don't know what quasiquotes are exactly, but a number of the recent Lean4 papers mention it, and the syntax looks similar to Lean3's [backtick quotation](https://leanprover-community.github.io/extras/tactic_writing.html#marios-backtick-cheat-sheet).)

Comment: And if we are being exaustive, I think [Metamath Zero](https://github.com/digama0/mm0) borrows some of this notation from Lean (maybe using different symbols).