# List of general purpose Coq sublanguages for defining custom tactics

Tags: coq, software-request

I've been tweaking [the Coq plugin template](https://github.com/ejgallego/coq-plugin-template) recently to try to get a feel for writing custom Coq tactics in OCaml.

It's tricky. You need to define an `.mlg` file (which gets lowered to an `.ml` file by `coqpp` [source](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/master/coqpp/coqpp_main.ml)) ... which appears to call into the `Mktop` library and do some other stuff to register your `.cmxs` file so Coq can find it.

Also, the exact details of how you build such a thing appear to be *very* sensitive to the exact version of Coq and dune that you're using. (I gave up on using `dune` or `coq_makefile -f _CoqProject` and just used a horrible `Makefile` to build all the artifacts manually.)

I'm wondering what the alternatives are to writing a Coq extension in this way.

From what I can tell, Coq ships with at least two "tactic scripting languages" of sorts:

- [Ltac](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html) -- the original one
- [Ltac2](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac2.html) -- the successor

And two more are maintained externally:

- [Mtac (and Mtac2?)](https://plv.mpi-sws.org/mtac/)
- [Rtac](https://gmalecha.github.io/reflections/2016/rtac-technical-overview)

I think a gathering a list of these sublanguages would be interesting.

I'd be especially interested in tactic-defining languages that are dynamically typed and have good support for pretty-printing ... and have simple syntaxes like Forth or Lisp.

Comment: Is [coq-elpi](https://github.com/LPCIC/coq-elpi) also the sort of tactic scripting language you mean?

Comment: @MikeShulman, yes, elpi definitely counts. Based on [this example from elpi's repo](https://github.com/LPCIC/coq-elpi/blob/master/examples/example_reflexive_tactic.v), it seems like it works at a basic level by defining a new syntax inside `lp:{{ ... }}` with `{{ ... }}` as a form of anti-quotation to insert Coq terms into the elpi subprogram.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet am a bit surprised that you had trouble with coq_makefile. It is quite straightforward to write a plugin nowadays, as long as you follow the pattern from the tutorial (layout and meta files). For this kind of trouble I recommend asking people on the Coq Zulip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I'll post this as an answer:

- [Coq-elpi](https://github.com/LPCIC/coq-elpi) is a plugin for writing Coq tactics in [ELPI](https://github.com/LPCIC/elpi), which is a dialect of [λProlog](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/%7Edale/lProlog/).  λProlog is a higher-order statically typed logic programming language.  I haven't used coq-elpi myself, but apparently one of its advantages is a higher-order abstract syntax representation of binders.