# What provers are using quote, quotations or quasiquotations?

Tags: quasiquotation, provers, big-list

This is a related question to

> [Is there a consolidated or partial list noting the use of quasiquotation with provers?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/988/5)

for which it seems there is no answer. However as there might be an answer some day am leaving that question and asking this question that others are dancing with in the comments of that question.

As this will be an open ended list type question, do not expect an accept vote on any answer. If you know of a prover (proof assistants, theorem provers, interactive theorem prover) that is making use of a system of quoting that derives from Lisp quote then just add an answer.

If you do not know what

- Lisp quote
  or
- quasiquotation

are please do not answer. It took me a few years before I really understood quasiquotations and a few more to learn much of the heredity.

Comment: As some of the comments in the other question are valid answers for this question, do **NOT** steal those from the person who made the comment.

Comment: "*If you do not know what Lisp quote or quasiquotation are do not answer.*" - why? What does this have to do with Lisp? You should add explanation if this is critical in that case.

Comment: Are you referring to some features exclusive to Lisp? It is entirely possible that someone is proficient in quotation and quasiquotation without learning Lisp at all.

Comment: @Wno-all *What does this have to do with Lisp?* The origin of *quote* and its heredity started from Lisp.

Comment: @Trebor *Are you referring to some features exclusive to Lisp?* No.

Comment: @Trebor *It is entirely possible that someone is proficient in quotation and quasiquotation without learning Lisp at all.* I don't doubt that. This is not requiring any to know Lisp. It is an **or** requirement; *Lisp quote or quasiquotation*. If you understand at least one of them them you probably understand enough to give an answer.

Comment: Perhaps write it the other way round. I parsed it as “Lisp {quote or quasiquotation}”, when I guess you intended “{Lisp quote} or quasiquotation”.

Comment: @mudri Thanks. I was wondering why everyone was reading it differently.

Comment: Since I don't know what quasi-quotations actually are, I'll leave this as a comment instead of an answer.  However, a number of Lean4 papers mention quasi-quotations when describing the macro system, e.g. [Beyond Notations: Hygienic Macro Expansion for Theorem Proving Languages](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.10490.pdf). Also, I'm not sure if this is the same as quasi-quotations, but you may want to see Lean3's [backtick quotation system](https://leanprover-community.github.io/extras/tactic_writing.html#marios-backtick-cheat-sheet).

Comment: @JasonRute *I don't know what quasi-quotations actually are* Then ask that as a question on the forum. I will try to answer it but I suspect their are others who could do better than me and I hope they do.

Comment: @JasonRute [Beyond Notations: Hygienic Macro Expansion for Theorem Proving Languages.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.10490.pdf) I would say that is a valid answer and would upvote it. Please post as an answer.

Comment: @JasonRute Lean3's [backtick quotation system](https://leanprover-community.github.io/extras/tactic_writing.html#marios-backtick-cheat-sheet). I would say that is a valid answer and would upvote it. Please post as a separate answer, multiple answers by the same person are allowed.

Comment: You mentioned ACL2 previously. Do you mind if I add it as an answer? Also I think it's important to distinguish between Lean and it's meta-language.

Answer (score 6):

[HOL Light-QE](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.00405), source available from [github](https://github.com/JacquesCarette/hol-light-qe). QE = quote-and-eval.

Comment: Could you give a simple example of what an expression using quasiquotations would look like in HOL Light-QE?

Comment: @Couchy see the various examples in the directory https://github.com/JacquesCarette/hol-light-qe/tree/master/Constructions .

Comment: @JacquesCarette Thanks, I was not sure where to look. Although a simple example would still help as someone not familiar with HOL Light.

Comment: The follow-up paper we were writing that would have contained many simple examples got stalled.

Answer (score 3):

[quasi-quote](https://github.com/UlfNorell/quasi-quote)

A quasi-quoting library for Agda, supporting automatic de Bruijn management. Very much work-in-progress. Requires the experimental branch of the standard library at commit bee4f912f or later.

Comment: It's quite likely that the bit about version requirements is out of date, given that the last commit was back in October 2020.

Answer (score 3):

Lean 4 has an extensive quasiquoting notation into `Lean.Syntax`, Lean 4's concrete syntax tree type:

```
`(fun $discrs* =>
    match $[$discrs:ident],* with
    | $ps1,* => $rhs1
    $alts:matchAlt*)
```

The "extended" antiquotation syntax displayed here is directly inspired by that in Rust. The details are described in §4.1 of [Beyond Notations: Hygienic Macro Expansion for Theorem Proving Languages](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.10490). As Lean 4 is implemented in Lean, syntax quotations are used pervasively throughout its implementation.

---

People familiar with Lean 3 might be surprised to hear that unlike in Lean 3, there is no built-in quotation support for the kernel term type `Lean.Expr` in Lean 4. The simple reason for that is that the need for it did not come up during development, as the terms that need to be synthesized in the core system usually consist of a single application of a certain constant to some arguments or similarly simple structures. The Lean 3 implementation was also limited by the lack of type information for the quoted expression. Gabriel Ebner's library [quote4](https://github.com/gebner/quote4) for type-safe expression quoting fixes this issue.

```
def betterApp {α : Q(Sort u)} {β : Q($α → Sort v)}
  (f : Q((a : α) → $β a)) (a : Q($α)) : Q($β $a) :=
q($f $a)

#eval betterApp q(Int.toNat) q(42)
```

Answer (score 2):

[ACL2](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/acl2/) supports quasiquotations entirely derived from lisp:

```
(defun app (binop args)
   (if args
      (if (cdr args)
          `(,binop ,(car args) ,(app binop (cdr args)))
          (car args))
      0))
      
(defmacro add (&rest rst)
   (app 'binary-+ rst))
```

For example we get

```
ACL2 !> (app 'binary-+ '(1 2 3))
(BINARY-+ 1 (BINARY-+ 2 3))

ACL2 !> (add 1 2 3)
6
```